# Bundling node.js modules

Tags: node.js, module

I have these modules I'd like to import into my project:

```
var ModuleA = require('./ModuleA.js'),
    ModuleB = require('./ModuleB.js'),
    ModuleC = require('./ModuleC.js'),
    ModuleD = require('./ModuleD.js');
```

Now, this works great, but **I'd like to bundle these and instead call one module that handles loading all these 'sub'modules**, like so:

```
// app.js ----------------------------

var Module = require('./Module.js');


// Module.js -------------------------

var ModuleA = require('./ModuleA.js'),
    ModuleB = require('./ModuleB.js'),
    ModuleC = require('./ModuleC.js'),
    ModuleD = require('./ModuleD.js');


// ModuleA.js ------------------------

exports.method = function() { return true }
```

Now, I'd like to be able to access the 'sub'bundles' exports, like so:

```
ModuleA.method();
```

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// ModuleA.js
module.exports.method = function () { return true; }

// Module.js
module.exports.A = require('./ModuleA');
module.exports.B = require('./ModuleB');

// app.js
var myModule = require('./Module');
myModule.A.method();
```

If you wish to call the method of `ModuleA` directly on `myModule` you need to re-export them in the `Modules.js` file like this:

```
// ModuleA.js
module.exports.method = function () { return true; }

// Module.js
module.exports.methodA = require('./ModuleA').method;
module.exports.methodB = require('./ModuleB').method;

// app.js
var myModule = require('./Module');
myModule.methodA();
```

Does this solve your issue?

Alternatively you might use [node-require-all](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all) that allows you to import multiple files at once and export them using a single object. An example might be:

```
var modules = require('require-all')({
  dirname    : __dirname + '/modules',
  filter     : /(Module.+)\.js$/,
  excludeDirs: /^\.(git|svn)$/
});
```

Afterwards, you have an object `modules` which contains the single modules as properties:

```
modules.ModuleA.method();
```

(I have not tested this code, but basically it should work like this.)

Comment: It did and it didn't. I can now access the method by calling `myModule.A.method()` - That works, but I prefer `myModule.method()`

Comment: Yeah, almost. :) But now I lose my automatic inheritance. I have to manually set all methods.

Comment: You can avoid this by directly assigning the module to be re-exported, but then you'll only be able to export one module. If you have multiple ones (as with `ModuleA`, `ModuleB` and so on) you only have the opportunity to either use the sub-namespacing, or resolving all the functions` names manually (at least right now I don't see another option).

Comment: A simple `module.exports = require('./ModuleA');` re-exports all of A, but only that of A.

Answer (score 0):

In Module.js, do something like this:

```
var ModuleA = require('./ModuleA.js'),
for (var exported in ModuleA) {
  exports[exported] = ModuleA[exported];
}
```

All objects (functions, etc) that were exported by ModuleA are now exported by Module too.

Comment: This has issues when ModuleA and ModuleB export things under the same name. Then the first one is overwritten by the second one.